# Aws Signature Version 4 Policy does not match example

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to generate an AWS4 signature to upload to a S3 bucket directly from the client's browser. I'm generating the signature in C# using the example here:

[AWS - Deriving the Signing Key with .NET (C#)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet)

To verify that the policy and signature being generated are correct, I've used the access keys and policy from the example here:

[AWS - Examples: Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST (Using AWS Signature Version 4)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

I've tried several methods to generate the policy and it does not match. I've even copy and pasted the exact policy string from the example. So why doesn't this work:

```
var policy = "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\"," +
                     "\"conditions\": [" +
                     "{\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"}," +
                     "[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"]," +
                     "{\"acl\": \"public-read\"}," +
                     "{\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"}," +
                     "[\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"]," +
                     "{\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"}," +
                     "{\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"}," +
                     "[\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"]," +
                     "{\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"}," +
                     "{\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"}," +
                     "{\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }]}";

// hash the Base64 version of the policy document and pass this to the signer as the body hash
var policyStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(policy);
return Convert.ToBase64String(policyStringBytes);
```

The example says that the policy string should be:

> 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

But the method above returns:

> 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

If I can't even get the policy string to match, then there is no hope in generating a matching signature.

Comment: Use `\n` for new line

Comment: *"If I can't even get the policy string to match, then there is no hope in generating a matching signature.*"  Actually, that isn't quite true in this case.  You're right, the signature won't match the example... but as long as the base64 encoding is *correct* for the policy document, and as long as the policy document is valid JSON (where whitespace has no meaning), you'll come up with a *different yet still valid* signature because it is a request that is physically different but logically equivalent.  Still, kudos for working by the book.

Comment: Oh, yeah... don't try building these things by hand.  Use a library that actually encodes JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically this is what you need to do.
based on the output from the documentation page, copy and paste the base64 code into https://www.base64decode.org/
and click decode.
This will show the decoded json content.

I did this and I compared it to your json content.
- as mentioned by @hjpotter92, you need to have \n for new lines
- you need to look at the spaces

the example shows

`<space>"conditions": [`
and
`<space><space><space><space>{"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},`

but your code shows

`"conditions": [`
and
`{"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},`

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to hjpotter92 and Titi Wangsa bin Damhore. @hjpotter92 clued me in and basically got me to where Titi got. It was a combination of the carriage return and the spaces. FYI in C# I had to use "\r\n" to get it to encode properly. On the plus side the signature now matches the example too :)